# Binding Mysqldata to datagridview cause error

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a table in mysql with a text, id and image (blob), now i need to display the data in a datagridview. This is what i did

```
MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new  

MySqlConnection(MySQLConnectionString);
mysqlCon.Open();

MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
string sqlSelectAll = "SELECT * from info";
MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelectAll, mysqlCon);

DataTable table = new DataTable();
MyDA.Fill(table);

dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(table,null); // Error at this line
```

I get the following error

[image]

How do i fix this

**EDIT**

I discovered the error is because some of the images are empty blob, when i selected all rows with images, i no longer get the error.

Is there anyway to checkmate this during binding

Comment: It doesnt have to do with binding - the DGV cant convert the BLOB to an image for the image column.  Could be an issue with the data.  Are you manually trying to do something?

Comment: hello please check the edit

Comment: Do you have code relating to the image column doing something?  The normal behavior for the DGV is to just show the broken image for DBNull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal behavior for a DGV Image column for a Null value is to simply show the classic broken image:

[image]

So be sure you don't have code somewhere doing something to cause the error.  Given the `invalid parameter` aksi be sure that there isn't a row with corrupted/bad data in it.  You can also specify a default image to use when the data is Null:

```
// class var for the image
private Image noImg = Properties.Resources.exclamation;
...
// set DS and specify null image for col:
dgv2.DataSource = new BindingSource(dtSample, null);
dgv2.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = noImg;
```

[image]

This may not do anything to solve your problem if the data is actually corrupted or if you have code that is doing something to cause the error (like a custom formatter).